# Is it possible to run a bash ssh command via MIT App Inventor to a local Raspberry Pi?

Tags: android, bash, ssh, app-inventor

TL;DR I want to create an Android app able to send a pause command to omxplayer running on a Raspberry Pi, via ssh.

I have been using RaspiCast (see Play store) for a Chromecast-like functionality on my sitting room TV, but since the Buster release of Raspbian I can cast youtube videos as usual but controls (pause, start) are non responsive any more and the progress bar is gone. Omxplayer connects to DBUS though, so it is possible to remotely send a commmand via send for various functions. For example running `sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' my_passwd) ssh pi@piTV_IP_address -p Port 'bash dbuscontrol.sh pause'` on bash on another local linux machine can pause and unpause playback on my TV RPi where I cast. So I want to create the simplest of android apps: a single Pause/Play button that when touched will send that ssh command to the RPi on the local network. After that it will be trivial to populate the app with buttons offering what is available via omxplayer's dbuscontrol.sh script.

The ActivityStarter block (Connectivity category) seems like the first place one should look but I can't make heads or tails of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried any of these: https://www.puttygen.com/putty-for-android

Comment: Yes, in fact I have JuiceSSH and Termux installed and I use them regularly for admin work. When I want to view videos on my TV however I want the simplicity I had when RaspiCast worked properly. I don't want to go through the hassle of typing a bunch of stuff just to pause a video. I want a big shiny Pause button with the functionality built in, that I can press right away.

Comment: I was thinking about using some sort of *post login script* to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to try the [Terminal / Shell Extension](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/zzW_HW7WLXQ/nAAxHktJCwAJ) by Juan Antonio
there also is a  [SSH Client Extension](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/h4A2ZgiWBtU/RJOatjFIAwAJ) by Andre Castro available, [Github respository](https://github.com/aluis-rcastro/AI2_ANDROID_SSH_CLIENT_EXTENSION)
for the App Inventor extensions diretory see here https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php

Comment: Andre Castro's extension did the trick. Kudos to the man! Looks like I will be modifying his sample app to get where I want. Thank you for your input!